# Sum of all indexes in a list with Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, sum

Imagine:

```
str = input( Muchos numeros separados por ',' : )
list = str.split(', ')

total = list(0) + list(1) + list(2) ... (Number of indexes in the anwer)
```

> How can I make it sum all of the indexes of a list?

Comment: why are you trying to add strings together when you already got the full string?

Comment: Never use names for your variables that are already defined as builtins like [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) and [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) because those builtins will we overwritten. ("Never" means: if you can't present a very, very, very good reason to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First map to `int` then `sum`:

```
print(sum(map(int,input("Muchos numeros separados por ',' :").split(', '))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterating over list you can find sum of all elements in list:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5];
sum = 0;
for i in mylist: # i will be 1,2,3,4,5 each loop
  sum+=i;
print(sum); # sum = 15
```

If its not your answer looking for, can you describe your problem better?

Comment: This gives me an error:    sum+=i;
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

```
a = list(map(int, input("Enter list values:").split()))
sum1 = 0
for x in a: # iterating over the list
    sum1 += x
print(sum1)
```